# Errors E0142 and E0020 while using two int* arrays with a for loop in a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to send two arrays to a function using pointers.

Next, I attempting to assign the dereferenced values from the two *arrays (sent as arguments in the function call) to the two (non-pointer) arrays where they can be manipulated with greater ease.

Note: there are no objects or clesses. I don't see any resson for dynamic memory handling (new, delete).

Original arrays in main:

```
int arr_fractions[2][7]
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

int arr_converted_values[2][7]
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };
```

This is the function call, in main:

```
arr_converted_values[2][7] = decimal_conversion(arr_decimals, *arr_converted_values, &var_fract_length);
```

Function:

```
int decimal_conversion(long double* arr_temp_decimals, int* arr_converted_values, int* var_fract_length)
{
    // pointer retrieval ----------------------------------------------------------------
    long double arr_temp_decimals[2][7]
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    int arr_temp_values[2][7]
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    int var_tempt_fract_value = *var_fract_length;

    for (int* var_temp_storage = 0; *var_temp_storage < *var_fract_length; *var_temp_storage++)
    {
        arr_temp_decimals[0][*var_temp_storage] = &arr_decimals[0][*var_temp_storage];
        arr_temp_decimals[1][*var_temp_storage] = &arr_decimals[1][*var_temp_storage];
        arr_temp_values[0][*var_temp_storage] = arr_converted_values[0][var_temp_storage];
        arr_temp_values[1][*var_temp_storage] = arr_converted_values[1][var_temp_storage];
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ...
    ...
    ...

    return (*arr_converted_values);
}
```

The three errors (below) that I am reciving are pointing to the array usage in the for loop, shown above.

E0142: expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type -->arr_*temp_*decinmals[0[*var_temp_storage]

E0142: expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type -->arr_*temp_*decinmals[1]*var_temp_storage]

E0020: identifier "arr_decimals" is undefined --- > &arr_decinmals[0][*var_temp_storage];

Comment: Writing elements on two separate lines does not automatically make it a 2d array, you need to put them in braces as well like `{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}`

Comment: `arr_converted_values[2][7] = decimal_conversion( . . .` You can assign to array elements, you can't assign a raw  array to another raw array. You could use this approach if you were using std::vector instead.

Comment: _" two (non-pointer) arrays where they can be manipulated with greater ease."_ Actually that creates more work and would use essentially the same syntax.

Comment: @AviBerger Then would you care to helo me do some pointer division? I am preparing to do a lot of mathematics with these values. hence I am trying to remove the pointers. I don't wish to do pointer math.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Pointer division isn't a term I understand.  You can post additional questions. Re this post, the intent of your code fragments isn't entirely clear to me, but [this is my attempt at a clean up using the same language features](https://godbolt.org/z/b11e1zEWK). If dimensions are not constants known at compile time that changes things. If doing a lot of matrix math, looking into a library for that is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your snippet.

`arr_temp_decimals` has redefinition `in  int decimal_conversion()`

> identifier "arr_decimals" is undefined

you didn't declare arr_decimals before in function.

arr_decimals is put in decimal_conversion(arr_decimals  ...).
So it will be

```
 arr_decimals[0][*var_temp_storage] = arr_decimals[0][*var_temp_storage];
```

arr_converted_values is a static 2D array. Consider changing the function parameter `int* arr_converted_values` to `int arr_converted_values[][7]`.

```
for (int* var_temp_storage = 0; *var_temp_storage < *var_fract_length; *var_temp_storage++)
arr_converted_values[0][var_temp_storage];
```

Pointer address cannot be used like `arr_converted_values[0][var_temp_storage]`.

Consider using [std::vector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/vector-class?view=msvc-170) .